# Setting "title" attribute on <xp:selectItem> in a Combo Box

Tags: xpages

I have a combo box with descriptions that are long in length. I'm trying to find the best way to show the full description. One thing I came across was the title attribute which causes a popup to show on hover. I tried to use the "attrs" property in XPages to add a title property, but xp:selectItem and xp:selectItems "attrs" do not appear in the HTML output.

Anyone have any ideas or a different method to try? Thanks for any thoughts.

**EDIT**: I ended up changing the combo box into a dialog pick list. This satisfied my requirements.

Comment: what do you mean by description? and how many characters are they?

Comment: By description I mean the value(s) that appear in the combo box. They can be anywhere from 20 to 200 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider using xe:djComboBox from Extension Library?
See http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/djComboBox_Dojo_Combo_Box_ddxl853

```
<xe:djComboBox id="djComboBox1" value="#{sessionScope.djComboBox1}"
            tooltipPosition="auto">
    <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="autoComplete" value="false">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="labelType" value="html">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:return new Array("<b>Apples</b>|apples", "Oranges|oranges")}]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xe:djComboBox>
```

Each element in array should have following format "label|value|description|disabled", where only label is mandatory. See: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc%2Fwpd_controls_cref_selectitems.html

Comment: I used a variation of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the description of your items is so long that they dont fit in a combobox you could either:

1. Change the length of the combobox using css.
2. Retrieve the description and only display a portion of it (lets say first 100 chars ).

Descriptions in comboboxes should be 'descriptive' ( hence the word description ). I would go for the second approach and add something in front of the description so the description is still usefull for the users.

For instance when have a list of projects. These titles are 100+ characters long. Instead of displaying the full description. Cut them of and use the project code as a prefix so that it will display

ProjectCode - {first 100 chars of description}.

This way users still know what they select because of the project code.

Comment: The issue with only displaying a portion of the description is some items in the combo box are very similar in wording and the ending part of the description is what could possibly make that selection unique. So I can't really strip out characters.